# Identify the scroll top position of iframe loaded in a static html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way to detect the top scroll position of iframe.
I have tried by using this

var iframetop = $('#iframe').contents().find('body').scrollTop();

But it is showing undefined.

I have declared this in on scroll function

Comment: Try `$('#iframe').contents().scrollTop()`

Comment: Hi Tobias , tried it still its showing undefined